# CSS not styling from external stylesheet

Tags: css

I got some CSS for buttons from this website: http://www.bestcssbuttongenerator.com.
 I put the code a stylesheet. Now when I try applying the styles for these buttons, they don't work. They *do* work, however, when I put the CSS in an inline stylesheet, between `style` tags. Any idea why?

```
<span id="">
<span id="some-id">Some text...</span>

</span>
<a href="#"><span class="button">Some text...</span></a><br>

<style>
.button {
-moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #54a3f7;
-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #54a3f7;
box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #54a3f7;
background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #007dc1), color-stop(1, #0061a7));
background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #007dc1 5%, #0061a7 100%);
background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #007dc1 5%, #0061a7 100%);
background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #007dc1 5%, #0061a7 100%);
background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #007dc1 5%, #0061a7 100%);
background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #007dc1 5%, #0061a7 100%);

background-color:#007dc1;
-moz-border-radius:3px;
-webkit-border-radius:3px;
border-radius:3px;
border:1px solid #124d77;
display:inline-block;
cursor:pointer;
color:#ffffff;
font-family:Courier New;
font-size:13px;
font-weight:bold;
padding:20px 24px;
text-decoration:none;
text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #154682;
}
.button:hover {
background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #0061a7), color-stop(1, #007dc1));
background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #0061a7 5%, #007dc1 100%);
background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0061a7 5%, #007dc1 100%);
background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #0061a7 5%, #007dc1 100%);
background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #0061a7 5%, #007dc1 100%);
background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #0061a7 5%, #007dc1 100%);

background-color:#0061a7;
}
.button:active {
position:relative;
top:1px;}
</style>
```

Comment: We have to see your page structure to see why - it may be overwritten by other styles.

Comment: The style tag is not supposed to be after the HTML... I know

Comment: Are you 100% sure your including path is correct? Also did you tried put your including line after all other css includes?

Comment: I'm positive my path is correct because other styles in the same stylesheet are applied. And it's the _only_ include.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the link for your CSS after all the other CSS file, in the HEAD tag. It will become more cascade specific.

**Also, override the specific ID of the button**: `#addToChrome-button`, to pass all the properties you need to set it.
Use this link as reference for [css specificity](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)

Comment: No, it didn't work. Does it have something to do with the browser-applied styles maybe?

Comment: Try debug with the inspector of chrome, it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: The inspector doesn't show the styles. All it has are the default ones.

Comment: Ok, got the solution: it is an ID you have to override with your style: #addToChrome-button. all the other CSS properties are passed. refactor the CSS with it. ;-)

Comment: Add all the style to the id. It's the basics, css101.

Comment: Read the article in the link